# Capistrano 3 deployment fails with access denied: dir_initialize tmp/passenger.h6D8mJy/apps.s

Tags: capistrano

On a machine running apache there are 3 rails apps running, all use capistrano for deployment, and they use passenger. The deployment scripts are standard. My predecessor set up the user `deploy` in textbook style, all 3 projects use the same capistrano version (3.8), and use the same directory structure on the server. All sit in a common directory within the `deploy` user's home. All use passenger, the same ruby and rails versions. They shared some linked directories, but otherwise the deployment scripts are all pretty trivial. My predecessor insists that in his times the deployment worked. We have still got his machine, and deployment does not work from his machine either-- only of this one project.

On `cap production deploy` of one of the three projects I always get a `Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ dir_initialize - /tmp/passenger.h6D8mJy/apps.s` error.

My only workaround is the following:
I log in on the production server, make myself superuser and change the owner of the /tmp directory to `deploy`. Then I run the deployment script, and it succeeds. (Then of course I change the owner of the directory back to root.)

So it *seems* as if the /tmp/passenger.something directory has set its owner wrong. Somehow I don't think this can be the problem though, since the other two scripts use the same directory and don't have this problem. Or do they? Who creates this directory and why, and where is ownership of this directory configured?

I thought it best if I just included the log, but I had to cut all of it... stackOverflow rejected my post because "this looks like spam").

```
INFO [e1c2bb25] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.3.1 do bundle exec rake assets:precompile as deploy@99.999.99.999
 DEBUG [e1c2bb25] Command: cd /home/deploy/projects/external-services/releases/20190423082459 && ( export RAILS_ENV="production" ; ~/.rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.3.1 do bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
 DEBUG [56ee67e8]   rake aborted!
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ dir_initialize - /tmp/passenger.h6D8mJy/apps.s
```

Comment: check this [thread](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/permission-denied-on-deploying-rails) you might find something helpful.

Comment: @UdAY I have found the workaround in this thread myself. My question is, how do I repair the situation? It is not as it should be; the workaround of setting the owner of the *global* /tmp directory to my `deploy` user is rather more like a hack than a solution.

Comment: you can give `deploy` user admin privileges to write/modify files in `tmp` directory right? rather than changing the `owner`

Comment: But my `deploy` user is the same for all three projects. So his privileges wrt /tmp should always be the same. Who creates this funny subdirectory `passenger.h6D8mJy`? It sounds like a temporary one given the name. So who creates it? The creator seems to set the owner wrong. Who does this? I don't know capistrano well enough to find out.

Comment: I am answering my own comment here: the passenger.xxxx directory is the passenger instance's working directory. Since passenger itself runs as root (it needs to spawn child processes running as potentially different users) the directory is owned by root. I still have not managed to find a solution to my problem, just by the bye.